Auto Assigning Permission Set system permissions
I have permission set that I want to include in a managed package, I defined custom object permissions and system permissions in it, and when I installed the package in the subscriber org, the custom object permissions are there but the system permissions are not.
Then I learned that the system permissions cannot be packaged, and also cannot be modified in a post install script since there is no 'SystemPermissions' like 'ObjectPermissions'.
So what options do I have to successfully auto assign the system permissions in the permission set without any manual user interaction?

One of the biggest misconceptions about publishing applications on the platform is that you have to automate everything. You should have a post-install script notify the user who initiated the installation that they should check your app's documentation about the instructions on what to do. This includes adding permissions and, preferably, explaining to your user why your app needs those permissions to begin with.
Besides some technical limitation that might have to do with it, from the tip of my tongue what I can say is the reason for this is probably security. Since system-level permissions apply to the whole org, not just your app, those need to be enabled by the admin with their consent in a more explicit way than just installing the app. Hence why its manual.

As an ISV we do want to automate as much as possible, but you are spot on that Salesforce restricts us for security reasons (but also because of platform limitations).
